# How to get image( using CGContext ) from the tableviewcell when tapped on the cell in iOS SDK

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios6

How to get imaged using CGContext same as the tableviewcell that I Tapped. I got the frame of the cell which I tapped. I had seen many examples of CGContext it only takes the size as the input and converting the image into that size.

But I want to get the Image of the tableviewcell as it is with the same frame. Can anyone suggest me how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess You need to club these two logic in appropriate place after your cell is being tapped. 
There is a method `- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;` to get the `CGRect` of your current cell.

1. Find the `CGRect` of the `UITableViewCell` being clicked.
2. Get the `CGSzie` from the `CGRect` of step 1.

   ```
   -(UIImage *) screenshot:(CGRect )cellRect onCell:(UITableViewCell)cell
    {
      UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cellRect.size);

      CGContextRef context=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
      [cell.layer renderInContext:context];

      UIImage *image=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
      UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

      return image;
    }
   ```

This should solve your problem, may need a few tweaks.

Here is usage:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UIImageView *imageV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[self screenshot:[tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] onCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]]];
imageV.frame = CGRectMake(0, 75, self.tableView.frame.size.width,100);

UIViewController *viewController = [[UIViewController alloc]init];
[viewController.view addSubview:imageV];

UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:viewController];
[self presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{
}];
```

}

Screens : Selected row 1

[image]

Loaded the image view onto new view controller

[image]

Comment: Here the context is taking only the image of the first cell even I tapped on the second cell.

Comment: @MonishKumar

Are you sure, this is the problem ?

Comment: Ok, Fine. There was a small modification. Now I am passing the cell & cell's rect as parameter so that cell.layer can be used. hope this fixes the problem. Try It. If works, don't forget to up vote.

Comment: Let me check with it.